# JavaScript syntax. which one to use?

Tags: javascript

I was actually looking forward to learning JavaScript, but I found out that there were different syntaxes used to write a JS code.

The one which starts off with html tags and script tags like this one:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.write("Hello World")
 </script>
 <p>This is web page body </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and another one which starts like this for example:

```
  var name = joe;
  dog Object = {

               }
```

(sorry if there is anything wrong with the syntax, as I'm new to this one)

so I want to know which syntax is what and why it is used
and which syntax is used for web development.

Comment: Your snippets are mistaken. First of all, delete those "enter code here" and then delete the <!-- and //--> lines

Comment: Secondly, TH is ```dog Object```? This kind of syntax doesn't exist in javascript.

Comment: Bro you have to learn so many things about Front End Engineering  ;)))

First of all try to learn simple HTML/CSS/JS and learn modern development approach... and for JavaScript fast learning go to -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: In the first snippet, only the part `document.write("Hello World")` is the actual JS. The rest is a HTML document that has the JS embedded using an inline script.

Comment: There are many ways of embedding JavaScript code in a web page. You can also load standalone script files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript